# Switch environment in docker file instead of in maven command

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run parallel builds using jenkins file and docker . I am currently able to run maven commands by putting a -f tag in maven command. I however want to move this in docker to decouple that from jenkinsfile

- I tried adding WORKDIR in dockerfile and trying to switch
- I tried using this in copyDocker.inside with "-w /containerworkspace" no luck

dockerfile

```
ARG BASE

FROM artifactory.XXX.XXXX.com/${BASE}

ADD . /containerworkspace/
RUN chmod -R 777 /containerworkspace
```

jenkinsfile code

```
def builtImage = self.docker.build(
                        "${imageName}:${branchNumber}-${buildNumber}",
                        " --build-arg BASE=${imageName}"
                                + " -f ${dockerFile}")
BBDocker copyDocker = dockerBuild.clone()

copyDocker.image("${imageName}:${branchNumber}-${buildNumber}").inside (){
self.sh("mvn -U clean install -f /containerworkspace/")
}
```

I am trying to eliminate **-f /containerworkspace/** from maven and put it into docker file somehow.

Comment: So if you use `-f` in jenkinsfile, you mean you will have at least 2 dockerfiles, and just a little difference between them? So now you want to combine the dockerfile, and use something like args to control? Could you make your question clear, and also add what's the difference of your dockerfiles?

Comment: -f ${dockerFile} is not the issue. the issue is having to using -f /containerworkspace/ . If I do not use that the parallel builds end up overwriting each other. But I wanna do this in a way where I dont have to specify that in maven command line(I plan to replace maven with something that can run any shell command)